# How to create a Cuke step definition that will test that only certainly results are displayed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, r, cucumber, haml

I've been searching high and low trying to implement a bunch of suggestions to crack this one, but none of them seem to work. Sorry if this has been answered elsewhere, I just couldn't find it!

Basically, I'm stuck writing a step definition that tests that the current view has been filtered by certain criteria. Here are the relevant steps:

```
  When I check the following ratings: PG, R
  And I uncheck the following ratings: G, PG-13, NC-17
  And I press "Refresh"
  Then I should see movies with the ratings: PG, R
```

And here are my step definitions for the latter two:

```
And /I press "Refresh"/ do
    click_button("Refresh")
end

Then /I should see movies with the ratings: (.*)/ do |ratings|
    page.should have_content ratings
end
```

The first one straight up doesn't work (says it's ambiguous), and the second one says that it can't find the text PG, R on the page. Cucumber is totally alien to me, and I am very lost! Any advice you can offer would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: As requested, this is the Haml that Capybara is operating on:

```
-#  This file is app/views/movies/index.html.haml
%h1 All Movies

= form_tag movies_path, :method => :get, :id => 'ratings_form' do
  = hidden_field_tag "title_sort", true if @title_header
  = hidden_field_tag ":release_date_sort", true if @date_header
  Include: 
  - @all_ratings.each do |rating|
    = rating
    = check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", 1, @selected_ratings.include?(rating), :id => "ratings_#{rating}"
  = submit_tag 'Refresh', :id => 'ratings_submit'

%table#movies
  %thead
    %tr
      %th{:class => @title_header}= link_to 'Movie Title', movies_path(:sort => 'title', :ratings => @selected_ratings), :id => 'title_header'
      %th Rating
      %th{:class => @date_header}= link_to 'Release Date', movies_path(:sort => 'release_date', :ratings => @selected_ratings), :id => 'release_date_header'
      %th More Info
  %tbody
    - @movies.each do |movie|
      %tr
        %td= movie.title 
        %td= movie.rating
        %td= movie.release_date
        %td= link_to "More about #{movie.title}", movie_path(movie)

= link_to 'Add new movie', new_movie_path
```

Comment: It sounds like your problem is more with Capybara rather than Cucumber. It would help if you share the html of the page (since that is what Capybara is working with).

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the original post to include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ambiguous means that you have a two same match so it doesn't know which one to use.
In web-steps.rb you already have

```
When /^(?:|I )press "([^"]*)"$/ do |button|
  click_button(button)
end
```

So you don't need to specify your own.

Answer (score 0):

You likely already have this step defined in `step_definitions/browsing_steps.rb`.

Delete your definition of `And /I press "Refresh"/`